# Maven Spring boot compilation error?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to compile a spring boot project with mvn package command but I am getting this error. I believe I have the JDK 1.7_55 installed.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.144s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 16 11:57:18 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project m
yproject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

Here is the output of the javac.

```
testspring>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55
```

And here is the output of maven version.

```
..\testspring>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-20     00:51:28+1100)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: What is output of "javac -version" ? it seems that you have not installed JDK in your system?

Comment: I have added the javac -version output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your `JAVA_HOME` to the location where you have your JDK installed, for example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Or with newer JDK:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Comment: Is JAVA_HOME environment variable for JRE or JDK? because I have it set to:C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 I have the PATH variable sett to JDK path.

Comment: Ok I followed Maven instructions and set the JAVA_HOME to JDK location.

Comment: This fixed a similar problem I had with `mvn spring-boot:run` (`javax/annotation/ManagedBean : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`), thanks!

Answer (score 6):

try the following

Go to

```
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs
```

And check whether it is pointing to your `JDK path`, if not, click on `edit` button and put the path you configured your `JAVA_HOME` enviroment.

And

Go to

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments
```

Select `JavaSE-1.6 or your required version` , click the `jdk checkbox` on the right.

Then right click on your project in eclipse and select `Mavan ->` `“update project configuration”`

Comment: I am trying to compile in CLI not Eclipse. Eclipse is working fine as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue because my java is referred to `JRE` rather than `JDk`.

I was using spring tool suite.

go to `windows->preferences->Java->installedJre's` and verify if it's pointed to JRE or JDK

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your project-> goto properties ->Select java build path
-> switch to Libraries -> there you have to change jre to jdk

[image]

I think this will solve your problem.